# Dart Provider get baseclass from derived class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have an abstract class with one concrete method and a few abstract methods

```
abstract class A with ChangeNotifier {

  void doSomething();

  void work(){
   doSomething();
   return true;
  }

}
```

I have another class which extends class A

```
class B extends A {

  void doSomething(){
   // dosomething
  }

}
```

I have then provided this class in routes

```
MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => B(),
    child: MyScreen(),
  ),
);
```

I would like to then access the concrete method work in my widget;

```
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var model = context.read<A>(); // This fails saying it cant find the the type
    var model = context.read<B>() as A; // This works
  }
}
```

Can I know if this is the wrong approach to what I want to?.
Is the way I have accessed the provider wrong?

Comment: You inherited B from A. Any public method A has, B has it as well. Why do you need an A, what would it be able to do that a B could not do just as well?

Comment: I think you forgot to notify the listeners when you mixing the A class with changenotifier

Comment: I have a common component which uses the method work(). I would then create different classes extending A but using different implementations of dosomething().  The component does a bunch of other stuff as well. So when required I would use the common Component and then provide it with a different flavour of A. @nvoigt

Comment: in my implementation I've setup notifiers @FotisPsarris